# Change point characters in lower diagonal of chart.Correlation()

Tags: r, charts, correlation

I’m tweaking PerformanceAnalytic’s chart.Correlation() function.

```
chart.Corr = function (R, histogram = TRUE, method = c("pearson", "kendall", 
    "spearman"), ...) 
{
    x = checkData(R, method = "matrix")
    if (missing(method)) 
        method = method[1]
    panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", use = "pairwise.complete.obs", 
        method, cex.cor, ...) {
        usr <- par("usr")
        on.exit(par(usr))
        par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
        r <- cor(x, y, use = use, method = method)
        txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
        txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep = "")
        #print(txt)
        strwidth(txt)
        if (missing(cex.cor)) 
            cex <- 1.5 #/strwidth(txt)
        test <- cor.test(x, y, method = method)
        Signif <- symnum(test$p.value, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
            cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), symbols = c("***", 
                "**", "*", ".", " "))
        #text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * (abs(r) + 0.3)/1.3)
        text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex)
        text(0.7, 0.7, Signif, cex = cex-0.25, col = 1) #col = 2
    }
    f <- function(t) {
        dnorm(t, mean = mean(x), sd = sd.xts(x))
    }
    hist.panel = function(x, ...) {
        par(new = TRUE)
        hist(x, col = "light gray", probability = TRUE, axes = FALSE, 
            main = "", breaks = "FD", pch=".")
        lines(density(x, na.rm = TRUE), col = "blue", lwd = 1)
        rug(x)
    }
    print(x)
    print(class(x))
    if (histogram) 
        pairs(x, gap = 0, lower.panel = panel.smooth(pch=“.”), upper.panel = panel.cor, 
            diag.panel = hist.panel, method = method, ...) #(pch=".")
    else pairs(x, gap = 0, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor, 
        method = method, ...)
}
```

When I instantiate, it doesn’t like my `lower.panel = panel.smooth(pch=“.”)` line. Specifically, it throws the error,

> Error in points(x, y, pch = pch, col = col, bg = bg, cex = cex) : 
>     argument "x" is missing, with no default

The error is definitely referring to that lower.panel line. In the original syntax of the function, no arguments at all passed to panel.smooth(), and it runs without a hitch:

```
function (R, histogram = TRUE, method = c("pearson", "kendall", 
    "spearman"), ...) 
{
    x = checkData(R, method = "matrix")
    if (missing(method)) 
        method = method[1]
    panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", use = "pairwise.complete.obs", 
        method, cex.cor, ...) {
        usr <- par("usr")
        on.exit(par(usr))
        par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
        r <- cor(x, y, use = use, method = method)
        txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
        txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep = "")
        if (missing(cex.cor)) 
            cex <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
        test <- cor.test(x, y, method = method)
        Signif <- symnum(test$p.value, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
            cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), symbols = c("***", 
                "**", "*", ".", " "))
        text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * (abs(r) + 0.3)/1.3)
        text(0.8, 0.8, Signif, cex = cex, col = 2)
    }
    f <- function(t) {
        dnorm(t, mean = mean(x), sd = sd.xts(x))
    }
    hist.panel = function(x, ...) {
        par(new = TRUE)
        hist(x, col = "light gray", probability = TRUE, axes = FALSE, 
            main = "", breaks = "FD")
        lines(density(x, na.rm = TRUE), col = "red", lwd = 1)
        rug(x)
    }
    if (histogram) 
        pairs(x, gap = 0, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor, 
            diag.panel = hist.panel, method = method, ...)
    else pairs(x, gap = 0, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor, 
        method = method, ...)
}
```

I'm trying to change the point characters in the scatterplots in the lower diagonal of the chart. I'd prefer to do it by tweaking the panel.smooth() syntax as described above, but am open to other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding your question, but if you are just trying to get the scatterplots in the bottom left of the diagonal to use a dot, then this code will do that for you:

```
# Loading example data from PerformanceAnalytics
data(managers)

# running chart.Correlation with points set to "." (using the argument pch=".")
chart.Correlation(managers[,1:8], histogram=TRUE, pch=".")
```

If you are trying to accomplish something more complex (and thus need to edit the function, itself), please clarify the question and I will update my answer.

Comment: This simple answer suffices, @enpitsu; thanks for this (smh).

I plan on modifying the function for other reasons, but thanks for this!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Sorry. Awarded bounty to the wrong answer. Giving you a bigger one in 23 hrs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you made that edit with a "word-processor" or copied it form a site that substitutes smate-quotes for regular quotes. NOT: `panel.smooth(pch=“.”)`. Try instead:

```
    panel.smooth(pch=".")
```